# Why text translated by "Google Translate" Web page and "Google Translate" API are different?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am trying to translate chinese language using my iOS application. Using "Google Translate API" introduces some errors in translation but with same text, Google translate webpage is not introducing errors in translation. "Google Translate" API response also include "&quot" and "&#39" characters. Below is code snippet related to it.

```
//Text recognized by tesseract.
text = [recText stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];

NSString * urlText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=%@&source=%@&target=%@&q=%@",_key,_sourceLanguage,_targetLanguage,text];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlText];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

    NSError *error;

    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];

    if(response != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSDictionary *data = dic[@"data"];
        NSArray *translations = data[@"translations"];
        for (NSDictionary *translation in translations)
        {
            translatedText = translation[@"translatedText"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more specific details. Show a clear example of some input, the undesired result, and the expected result.

Comment: Ask Google.  It's their API and website.